# Show that F(x) is a distribution function of a probability on $R$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

$\textbf{PROBLEM}$: Suppose that a function $F$ is given by $$F(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}1_{[\frac{1}{i}, \infty)}$$
Show that it is a distribution function of a probability on $R$.

So as to prove that $F(x)$ is a distribution function of probability, first of all I cannot understand how I can see the l.h.s above as a function of X (and so computing limit of $F(x)$ as $x$->$\infty$ and as $x$ -> $-\infty$ or showing that $F(x)$ is a monotone non-decreasing function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your question about reading it "as a function of $x$": it should be $$F(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} 1_{[1/i, \infty)}(x).$$
This expression uses indicator functions: the indicator of a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $1_A(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in A \\ 0 & x \notin A\end{cases}$.

You can verify the properties of a CDF if you wish. One other approach is to notice directly that this is the CDF of the distribution of a random variable $X$ that has $P(X = 1/i) = \frac{1}{2^i}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: Thank You a lot @angryavian

Answer (score 2):

The function $F(x)$ can be written thus:
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
   \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{2^k}} & \mbox{  si   } x\geq 1\\
   \sum_{k=m}^\infty{\frac{1}{2^k}} & \mbox{  si   } \frac{1}{m}\leq x< \frac{1}{m-1}\\
   0 & \mbox{  si   } x<0
  \end{cases}$$
_
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
   1 &\mbox{  si   } x\geq 1\\
   1-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}{\frac{1}{2^k}} & \mbox{  si   } \frac{1}{m}\leq x< \frac{1}{m-1}\\
   0 & \mbox{  si   } x<0
  \end{cases}$$
_
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
   1 &\mbox{  si   } x\geq 1\\
   \dfrac{1}{2^{m-1}} & \mbox{  si   } \frac{1}{m}\leq x< \frac{1}{m-1}\\
   0 & \mbox{  si   } x<0
   \end{cases}$$
Now you can see that $F(x)\rightarrow 1$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$ and  $F(x)\rightarrow 0$ when $x\rightarrow -\infty$, furthermore $F(x)$ is a step function, that's mean the left limit exists for all $x$. This demostrates that $F(x)$ is a distribution function of probability.